# Setting/getting global variables in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

I am writing an app which is a sort of dictionary - it presents the user with a list of terms, and when clicked on, pops up a dialog box containing the definition. The definition itself may also contain terms, which in turn the user can click on to launch another definition popup.

My main app is stored in 'myViewController.m'. It calls a custom UIView class, 'CustomUIView.m' to display the definition (this is the dialog box that pops up). This all works fine.

The text links from the CustomUIView then should be able to launch more definitions. When text is tapped in my CustomUIView, it launches another CustomUIView. The problem is, that this new CustomUIView doesn't have access to the hash map which contains all my dictionary's terms and definitions; this is only available to my main app, 'myViewController.m'.

Somehow, I need to make my hash map, *dictionaryHashMap*, visible to every instance of the *CustomUIView* class. *dictionaryHashMap* is created in *myViewController.m* when the app opens and doesn't change thereafter.

I don't wish to limit the number of CustomUIViews that can be opened at the same time (I have my reasons for doing this!), so it would be a little resource intensive to send a copy of the *dictionaryHashMap* to every instance of the CustomUIView. Presumably, the solution is to make *dictionaryHashMap* a global variable.

**Some of my code:**

From myViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.dictionaryHashMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // initialise the dictionary hash map
    //... {Code to populate dictionaryHashMap}
}

// Method to pop up a definition dialog
- (void)displayDefinition:(NSString *) term
{
    NSArray* definition = [self.dictionaryHashMap objectForKey:term]; // get the definition that corresponds to the term
    CustomUIView* definitionPopup = [[[CustomUIView alloc] init] autorelease]; // initialise a custom popup
    [definitionPopup setTitle: term];
    [definitionPopup setMessage: definition];
    [definitionPopup show];
}

// Delegation for sending URL presses in CustomUIView to popupDefinition
#pragma mark - CustomUIViewDelegate
+ (void)termTextClickedOn:(CustomUIView *)customView didSelectTerm:(NSString *)term
{
        myViewController *t = [[myViewController alloc] init]; // TODO: This instance has no idea what the NSDictionary is
        [t displayDefinition:term];
}
```

From CustomUIView.m:

```
// Intercept clicks on links in UIWebView object
- (BOOL)webView: (UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [myViewController termTextClickedOn:self didSelectTerm:request];
        return NO;
    } 
    return YES;
}
```

Any tips on how to make the *dictionaryHashMap* visible to *CustomUIView* would be much appreciated.

I have tried making the *dictionaryHashMap* global by doing the following:

- Changing all instances of 'self.dictionaryHashMap' to 'dictionaryHashMap'
- Adding the line 'extern NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryHashMap;' to *CustomUIView.h*
- Adding the following outside of my implementation in *myViewController.m*: 'NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryHashMap = nil;'

However, the dictionaryHashMap remains invisible to CustomUIView. As far as I can tell, it actually remains a variable which is local to *myViewController*...

Comment: You say, *"it would be a little resource intensive to send a copy of the dictionaryHashMap to every instance of the CustomUIView".*  That would be true but since all you're sending in the normal case is the **address** of the hash map, it's not a big deal and is likely to be easier to work with than trying to implement something global.

Comment: You really need to avoid global variables for such a trivial task. Just add a reference to CustomUIView instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not resource-intensive to pass around the reference (pointer) to `dictionaryHashMap`.  A pointer to an object is only 4 bytes.  You could just pass it from your view controller to your view.

But I don't know why you even need to do that.  Your view is sending a message (`termTextClickedOn:didSelectTerm:`) to the view controller when a term is clicked.  And the view controller already has a reference to the dictionary, so it can handle the lookup.  Why does the view also need a reference to the dictionary?

Anyway, if you want to make the dictionary a global, it would be more appropriate to initialize it in your app delegate, in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  You could even make the dictionary be a property of your app delegate and initialize it lazily.

#### UPDATE

I didn't notice until your comment that `termTextClickedOn:didSelectTerm:` is a class method.  I assumed it was an instance method because `myViewController` starts with a lower-case letter, and the convention in iOS programming is that classes start with capital letters.  (You make it easier to get good help when you follow the conventions!)

Here's what I'd recommend.  First, rename `myViewController` to `MyViewController` (or better, `DefinitionViewController`).

Give it a property that references the dictionary.  Whatever code creates a new instance of `MyViewController` is responsible for setting this property.

Give `CustomUIView` properties for a target and an action:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id target;
@property (nonatomic) SEL action;
```

Set those properties when you create the view:

```
- (void)displayDefinition:(NSString *)term {
    NSArray* definition = [self.dictionaryHashMap objectForKey:term];
    CustomUIView* definitionPopup = [[[CustomUIView alloc] init] autorelease]; // initialise a custom popup
    definitionPopup.target = self;
    definitionPopup.action = @selector(termWasClicked:);
    ...
```

In the view's `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method, extract the term from the URL request and send it to the target/action:

```
- (BOOL)webView: (UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        NSString *term = termForURLRequest(request);
        [self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:term];
        return NO;
    } 
    return YES;
}
```

In the view controller's `termWasClicked:` method, create the new view controller and set its dictionary property:

```
- (void)termWasClicked:(NSString *)term {
    MyViewController *t = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    t.dictionary = self.dictionary;
    [t displayDefinition:term];
}
```

Comment: Possibly the problem lies in the fact that I call *displayDefinition* using a new instance of *myViewController*, and this instance doesn't have a *dictionaryHashMap*..? How would I call *displayDefinition* without having to create a new instance? It seems that I can't access the instance variable *dictionaryHashMap* in a class method...

Comment: Thanks. *myViewController* is in fact the parent class for the whole app (i.e. it is the one which starts when the app is run). As such, I never 'call' it as far as I can tell. Where then, would I be able to attach a '.dictionary' property to the *myViewController* class?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that will be used as singleton. [Example](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/).

Answer (score 0):

You Should always keep your data in separate class as the mvc pattern suggest and that could be achieved by using a singleton class for all your dictionary terms and accesing them from every custom view when needed.